# Unable ignore the eclipse setting in gitignore

Tags: eclipse, git, gitignore

```
I am using
```

`/*/.settings/*`

OR
 `/*/.settings/`

to ignore eclipse setting.

> abc.host.client/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs

```
but unable to ignore the following files.
```

> `abc.host.client/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml`
>
> `abc.host.client/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component`

I am using git version **1.7.1**. May I know what is the problem?Thank You.

Comment: When did you add this to `.gitignore` ?

Comment: ..dt.core.prefs already commited into Git server.
..common.project.facet.core.xml & ..common.component are newly modified. But I already try git rm -r --cached <file>. Unfortunately no use.

Comment: In many case, those settings folder are better being shared with your teammates and committed.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have added `/*/.settings/*` recently to `.gitignore`, you need to clear the cache of `.gitignore`.

```
git rm --cache .gitignore
```

After that commit as usual.

Comment: This `/*/.settings/*` already added into .gitignore and committed into Git Server last time. But do not know why it unable ignore that 2 files.

Comment: @user1238353 : did you try `git rm --cache .gitignore`,a nd after that `git push origin master --force`

Comment: yup. I have try git rm --cache .gitignore. But this will removed my .gitignore.  git push origin master --force will push the file into server?